# SQLite query with lists

Tags: android, sqlite, list, arraylist

I am passing the `ArrayList<Integer>` to SQLite Query and it prints like this but I am getting no output

`SELECT  * FROM categoriesData WHERE categoryid IN [49, 67, 23]`

shows null values

But it prints the values if it is in round braces.

`SELECT  * FROM categoriesData WHERE categoryid IN (49, 67, 23)`

How to make them to round braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM categoriesData WHERE categoryid IN " + Arrays.toString(myList.toArray()).replace("[", "(").replace("]", ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM categoriesData WHERE categoryid IN " +
                   "(" + yourArrayList.get(0) + ", " +
                         yourArrayList.get(1) + ", " +
                         yourArrayList.get(2) + ");" ;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But I dont know how many elements will be there in list it will vary dynamically